# Is it possible to restore a full system Back In Time backup from a BIOS system to another UEFI system?

Tags: uefi, bios, restore

1. I have backup my whole Ubuntu system(/) using Back in time and i need to restore it to different PC, is it possible?
2. I have used Bios  on my old PC, is itpossible to restore it to my new PC but with the differce my new pc starting with  UEFI?

Comment: Which method you followed for backup? tar archive/rsync/fsarchiver or something like remastersys? Did you check this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)? & also check if you can boot into legacy on your new PC. Other things to care are fstab file(change partition etc) and closed source driver (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Back in Time, so I can't comment on it specifically; however, there are two possible stumbling blocks, neither of which is insurmountable:

- **Partition table type** -- Most BIOS-mode installations use the old MBR partitioning system, whereas most EFI-mode installations use the newer GPT partitioning system. If the backup software insists on repartitioning the disk when you restore data, it might force use of MBR. At least some EFI computers can boot from MBR disks, though, so this might not be too much of a problem; and even if your computer can't boot from an MBR disk in EFI mode, you should be able to convert it to GPT [by using `gdisk`.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html)
- **Boot loader installation** -- The restore process *might* install a BIOS-mode boot loader on the disk, in which case the restored system will probably boot in BIOS mode. If you want to boot in EFI mode, though, you'll need to install an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux. Several are available; [see here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for detailed information on all of them, including information on how to install them. Note that you'll need an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is a FAT32 partition to hold the EFI boot loader. Chances are your backup software won't create this partition, so you'll have to do so yourself.

One more point: Any restore of one computer's software to another one poses some risk of failure or a need to reconfigure things because of the new hardware (video card, network devices, etc.). Such changes are less likely to be required with a modern Ubuntu than with, say, a distribution from a decade ago, but you should be aware of the possibility that you'll need to tweak something. In some cases, it may be easier to do a fresh installation and then copy over your home directory from the old computer to the new one.